# What's the takeaway message for Chanuka?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chanuka

One of the oft-cited teachings of [Rav Hirsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch) is that every Jewish holiday contains an infusion of *kedusha* (holiness) and a lesson, both of which aren't only important in and of themselves, but rather so that they can be carried into the days that follow the holiday, the whole year round. The lesson of Pesach, for example, might include elements of freedom (particularly from *chametz* = *yetzer hara*) and gratitude (to God for taking us out of Egypt), among other things.

**What's the takeaway message for the holiday of Chanuka?**

Comment: [tag:drash]? [tag:samson-raphael-hirsch]?

Comment: On [hirsch]: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19527651#19527651 ....on [drash]; I don't know, does it fit?

Comment: I think tagging with the RSRH tag makes sense, as you're asking for the takeaway message assuming it exists, which is according to RSRH. Just MHO (and I haven't yet read the chat transcript).

Answer (score 2):

R' Yaakov Weinberg explained that the lesson of Chanuka was that of survival in exile.  The lesson of Chanuka was that in the darkness we can create our own light.

Comment: Summarizing a 30 minute shiur into a 20-word take-away message waters it down, but what can ya do.

Comment: Is "survival in exile" really the lesson of a _Chag_ commemorating events that took place in _Eretz Yisra'el_ (events that, in a way, marked the beginning of renewed Jewish sovereignty there)? I would have thought that would be a more appropriate lesson for _Purim_.

Comment: @TamirEvan That's a good point, but there were certainly elements of exile in the Chanukah story; we were kicked out of the Temple, for instance, and we lost governmental autonomy over the Land of Israel.

Comment: @TamirEvan Yes - there was no Shechina in the second Temple.  R' Hirsch actually writes that the entire second Temple period was just a pre-Galus focus group. R' Weinberg's driving point was that whatever the message of Chanuka is, the starting point is that it was not an intrinsically necessary message, otherwise it would have been there from the beginning of the existence of the Jewish nation.  It only became relevant at that point.

Comment: Purim was _amidst_ "hester panim," Hashem being hidden.  Chanuka is the long-term transition into that mode of existence.

Comment: @Shokhet If you're talking about what led up to the Maccabean Revolt, we were still allowed in the Temple, only it was run by Hellenizers. Also, loss of governmental autonomy over land is not the same as being in exile. Moreover, _Chanukah_ commemorates not the loss of those things, but the start of regaining them. Otherwise, Couldn't the same thing be said for _Pesach_ with regard to _Galut Mitzrayim_ (which was more of an actual exile)?

Comment: @YeZ Fair enough (though personally I don't see it), but shouldn't that (the _Chanukah_ specific parts, at least) be in the answer itself?

Comment: @TamirEvan I suppose - I tried to keep it to a bite-sized "take away message" instead of a whole _derasha_ about Chanukah, but if I have time I can add in some background info.

Comment: @TamirEvan: Hm...you have a good point.

Comment: Is there a Mi Yodeya policy about making answers as bite-sized as possible? Also, I thought that giving the reason for a point being the takeaway message was implied in the question.

Comment: @TamirEvan No such policy that I know of, but "take away message" to me implied "not a whole thesis, but a short to-the-point message."

Comment: @YeZ "_R' Weinberg's driving point was that whatever the message of Chanuka is, the starting point is that it was not an intrinsically necessary message_ ..." Wouldn't that mean that, according to R. Weinberg, there is no "**the** takeaway message for the holiday of Chanuka"?

Comment: @TamirEvan No, that was what pushed him to say that the message was what he said it was - it had to be something that only became relevant at that point. "Driving point" = point that drove him.  I may have used the phrase incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

[Rav Reuven Leuchter in a shiur](http://ravleuchter.com/?p=4540) says the message is "mesirus nefesh" for Avodah (just as the Maccabees were prepared to lay their lives down [moser nefesh] for the avodah), especially starting around 23 mins 30 secs.
Our avodas HaShem has to be real. 
Particularly our tefilla has to be real, serious. We should decide to stay for davenning to the end. We must say the words so it is clear that we are speaking to Someone.

And see YeZ's [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52660/whats-the-takeaway-message-for-chanuka/52672#comment138610_52661)!

Comment: You could try and summarize how R. Leuchter sees "'mesirus nefesh' for Avodah" as a lesson from _Chanukah_ (rather than just explaining what it means).

Comment: @TamirEvan Done as requested.

Comment: This fits very well with what the Bach writes the reason decrees were imposed on the Jews because they were lazy in their avodah